# 'I disagree that either of these options is correct'

Tags: grammar, phrases, meaning-in-context, differences, negation

I thought that I mastered the usage of "either" (and neither)...only to be unsure about the following sentence (which I heard, not that it was me who said it):

> I disagree that either of these options is correct.

From what I have learned, either here should express "one or the other" (or any but only from two things). But then the sentence does not make much sense to me.
Occasionally, I have heard "either" to mean "both" (but then why not use "both"?) as in:

> Unfortunately I was sitting at the table with smokers on either side
>   of me.

Comment: The person you are disagreeing with has probably not suggested that _both_ options are correct, but that _one_ of them is. Maybe another person thinks the other option is correct. You don't agree with either of them. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: @KateBunting So basically..I agree with neither of them?

Comment: Weirdly, I change pronunciation from the long e either to the long i either in these constructions. Apparently, it's a family idiolect thing. But at least it helps with verb choice. I would use *either are correct* here in casual speech, but would rearrange the sentence when writing so that it didn't use *disagree*, or *disagree* appears in a separate clause from either/neither. I disagree (with your claims) - neither of these options are correct. Losing the *that* solves most of the problem.

Comment: @PhilSweet I wouldn't use "either are correct" at all. For me "either" refers to a choice between one of two alternatives but a choice where both choices are, in some way, equivalent. For example "Either of those streets will take you the Town Hall" or "I wouldn't want to eat in either of those restaurants". In the case of "I had smokers on either side of me" this means "Whether I turned to left or right the person sitting there was smoking.

Comment: @BoldBen Then you, so if I get it right, I could say: There were new malls in either town OR There were new malls in both towns.

Comment: "So basically..I agree with neither of them? " Yes, I thought that was your intended meaning.

Comment: @JohnV I wouldn't say "There were new malls in either town" because there is no choice involved. However you could say "We could open our shop in the new mall in either town". By implication that carries the information that there are new malls in both towns and expresses the idea that there is a binary choice of location for the shop.

Comment: @BoldBen Thank you. The reason I ask is - I saw a sentence: "There was a cathedral in either town", written by a native speaker. Isn't it the same as this dictionary examples "there were smokers on either side of the table"? Also does not involve a choice, I believe.